# Counting how many time a value appeared in array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, frequency

I've got a task in which I have an array, let's say {2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5}
and using only one loop I have to find minimum and maximum. This one I already have. I also have have to count (in the same loop) how many times this minimum and maximum appeared. I have problem with that one. I can only use one loop!
Output should be like:
Minimum: 2 Appeared: 3 times
Maximum: 5 Appeared: 4 times

The code:

```
int size = sizeof(tab) / sizeof(int);
int max = tab[0];
int min = tab[0];
int minCounter = 1;
int maxCounter = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << "Tab[" << i+1 << "]: " << tab[i] << endl;
    if (tab[i] > max) {
        max = tab[i];
        maxCounter++;
    }
    if (tab[i] < min) {
        min = tab[i];
        minCounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: when you encounter a new maximum, the times you have seen it so far must be 1.

Comment: please show what you tried and explain how it fails

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your code, you are not printing right values and the code is not sufficient to print out the desired output. You should decide to print the output out of the loop and if you want to count to max and min appear time, you should add one more if statement to check when max == tab[i] and min = tab[i]. If you do this after if (tab[i] > max) and if (tab[i] < min) you don't need to initialize minCounter and maxCounter at 1 otherwise they need to be initialized at 1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a `max_count` variable, resetting it to 1 every time you encounter a new maximum.

(The rest of the solution is left as an exercise to the reader...)

Comment: Yes, I thought about it and it worked except one situation. When the element was first in array then it didn't count the rest of the same elements

Comment: @Mrfk - That sounds like a bug then ;)

Comment: Probably I've done something wrong. Here's the code:

Comment: @Mrfk: common policy is not to post code in comments as that is difficult to read.

Comment: Yup, I realized that, that's why I deleted the comment and pasted the link :p

Comment: @Mrfk:  Please don't post links as firewalls prevent people from following them.  Please **edit your post** with the text instead.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Done, my fault :)